# Получить текущее положение другого пользователя из JavaScript

Tags: api, google-maps, геолокация

Google предоставил пользователям возможность делиться своим местоположением с другими пользователями.
Вот инструкция: https://support.google.com/maps/answer/7326816?hl=ru&co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid

Тот, с кем поделились, геолокацией видит только текущее местоположение.
Я хотел бы сохранять историю геолокации.

Искал информацию в интернете и в документации, но не нашел ничего, что могло бы помочь в этом вопросе.

**Можно ли внедрить в web-страницу JS-код, который получит доступ к данным геолокации другого пользователя?**
Технически код JS можно внедрить из консоли, либо написав браузерное расширение, но вот как получить данные?
В идеале, хотелось бы ловить события обновления маркера.
Если так не получается, то в setInterval опрашивать google о позиции друга.